# Extracting raster contours to DXF

Tags: qgis, dxf

I'm using Raster>Extraction>Contours... I specify the input Raster, use the Select dialog to type a name and pick the DXF file type from the pulldown. But instead of a DXF, I'm getting a folder named [NAME].dxf with a shapefile inside that folder. I remember having this problem before and got around it somehow.

Am I doing something wrong, or what's going on?

[image]

Comment: you can see in the script that it is running that it is specifying "ESRI Shapefile"... its just running GDAL (http://www.gdal.org/gdal_contour.html) .. you could likely edit that string and substitute "AutoCAD DXF" for "ESRI Shapefile"